# Is the following function Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes

Given a vector $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{S\times A}$ where $S$ and $A$ are sets of finite cardinality, for $0<\gamma<1$ define the function $H_{w}:\mathbb{R}^{S\times A} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{S\times A}$ as $H_{w}Q(s,a) := w\left(r(s,a)+ \gamma \sum_{s' \in S}p(s'|s,a)\displaystyle\max_{a \in A} Q(s',a)\right)+(1-w)\displaystyle\max_{a \in A}Q(s,a).$ Here $|r(s,a)| \leq R ~ \forall ~ (s,a) \in S \times A$ and $p(\_|s,a)$ is a probability mass function on $S$ for any given $(s,a) \in S \times A$ and $0<w<w^*$ with $w^*=\displaystyle\max_{(i,a)}\left\{\frac{1}{1-p(i|i,a)}\right\}.$

Note:

1. $H_w$ is a contraction with respect to the max-norm/infinity-norm on  $\mathbb{R}^{S\times A}$ with contraction factor $(1-w+\gamma w)$
2. Note the possibility of $w>1$.

Is the function $H_wQ$ jointly Lipschitz in $w$ and $Q$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In view of your Note 1, it appears that the definition of $H_w Q(s,a)$ has to corrected as follows:
$$H_w Q(s,a):=\gamma w\left(r(s,a)+\sum_{s'\in S}p(s'|s,a)\max_{a\in A}Q(s',a)\right)
+(1-w)\max_{a\in A}Q(s,a).$$
(Your definition is missing $\gamma$.)

Now it is clear that $H_w Q$ is not Lipschitz in $(w,Q)$, because $H_w Q$ is "of degree $2$" (rather than "of degree $\le1$") in $(w,Q)$. In fact, $H_w Q$ is not Lipschitz even in $w$. Indeed, taking $Q$ to be an arbitrary real constant $q$ and letting $r=0$, we have
$$H_w Q(s,a)=h(w,q):=\gamma wq+(1-w)q=(1-(1-\gamma)w)q.$$
The partial derivative of $h(w,q)$ in $w$ is $(1-\gamma)q$, which can be however large for large $q$. So, indeed $H_w Q$ is not Lipschitz even in $w$.

---

Note 1: $h(w,q)$ is a polynomial in $(w,q)$ of degree $2$.

Note 2: With your current definition, too, $H_w Q$ will not in general be Lipschitz even in $w$. In that case, we can let $Q(s,a)$ take two distinct values, depending on $s$.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct, there is a typo. Edited the statement accordingly. We agree with your solution. The function is not Lipschitz with respect to $w$. We also carried out a similar calculation and obtained the same